# Mudar os ícones do menu Navigation Drawer

Tags: android

Gostaria de saber como faço para trocar esses ícones:

[image: Captura de tela de uma aplicação Android com vários uma NavigationDrawer aberta, contendo vários menus. Do lado esquerdo de cada menu, há um ícone não-relacionado com a descrição do menu, dando a entender que são ícones padrão]

Eu achei a tela, mas quando clico não me mostra o caminho para fazer a alteração e sim só cores em RGBA :

[image: Captura de tela de um código XML]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Percebi que você está usando o Padrão Navigation Drawer, então para mudar os ícones e personalizar como você quiser, basta ir na pasta `menu` e no arquivo `activity_main_drawer.xml` e fazer as mudanças como quiser.

Veja um exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:title="@string/menu1">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_check_box"
            android:id="@+id/nav_um"
            android:title="@string/categoria1" />
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_check_box"
            android:id="@+id/nav_dois"
            android:title="@string/categoria2" />
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_check_box"
            android:id="@+id/nav_tres"
            android:title="@string/categoria3" />
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_check_box"
            android:id="@+id/nav_quatro"
            android:title="@string/categoria4" />
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_check_box"
            android:id="@+id/nav_cinco"
            android:title="@string/categoria5" />
        <item
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_check_box"
            android:id="@+id/nav_seis"
            android:title="@string/categoria6" />
    </menu>
    </item>
        <item android:title="@string/menu2">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_check_box"
                android:id="@+id/nav_sete"
                android:title="@string/categoria7" />
            <item
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_check_box"
                android:id="@+id/nav_oito"
                android:title="@string/categoria8" />
            <item
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_check_box"
                android:id="@+id/nav_nove"
                android:title="@string/categoria9" />
            <item
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_check_box"
                android:id="@+id/nav_dez"
                android:title="@string/categoria10" />
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item android:title="@string/menu3">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_sobre"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_storage_24dp"
                android:title="@string/menusobre" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_sair"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_clear_24dp"
                android:title="@string/menusair" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

Perceba que a IDE Android Studio oferece uma ferramenta muito útil, que é o `Vector Asset` para você criar um ícone personalizado, para fazer isso basta clicar com o botão direito em cima da pasta `drawable` > `New` > `Vector Asset`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que acima o novo ícone está na pasta `drawable`, então basta agora você editar seu arquivo `activity_main_drawer.xml`, dessa maneira:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:title="@string/menu1">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_3d_rotation_black_24dp"
                android:id="@+id/nav_um"
                android:title="@string/categoria1" />
```

---

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado. Você me ajudou muito. Agora sim. Valeu mesmo.